# Warum gibt es hier ein "an"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, preposition, tense

Ich finde es verwirrend, wenn ich diesen Satz lese:

> Der Rohbau war fertig, als der Zweite Weltkrieg begann. Danach wurde
>   nicht weiter an der Nazi-Anlage gebaut.

Warum sagt man nicht

> Danach wurde nicht weiter die Nazi-Anlage gebaut.

Danke schon mal im Voraus.

Comment: Man kann auch "nicht weiter" schreiben, aber dann muss die Wortstellung sein: "Danach wurde die Nazi-Anlage nicht weitergebaut." (Das Subjekt darf nicht zwischen Negation und Bezugswort stehen.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es gibt viele Möglichkeiten, denselben Inhalt mit unterschiedlichen Mitteln auszudrücken. Auch mit deinem Satz ist das der Fall. Achte aber darauf, dass es gerade in deinem Satz um den **Prozess** geht, eher als um eine abgeschlossene Handlung. Und die Bedeutung drückt man in diesem Fall *besser* mit dem Verb "bauen" mit der *Rektion* "an etwas (Dativ) aus.  Das wäre dann sehr idiomatisch.

Vergleiche: ich arbeite gerade an meiner Masterarbeit - I'm working on my master's thesis. Solche Kontruktionen braucht man im Deutschen, weil es kein Continuous Tense im Deutschen gibt. ("I am doing something").

"Weiter bauen" würde dagegen bedeuten, dass die Anlage schon fertig war, und wurde noch größer gebaut.

Nebenbemerkung: die Wortfolge ist in deinem Satz leider falsch. In dem Beispiel muss das Objekt auf der dritten Position stehen, z.B. "Danach wurde die Nazi-Anlage nicht weitergebaut".

Comment: Danke, es ist klar. Aber ich habe noch eine Frage: Warum muss das Objekt in meinem Satz auf der dritten Position stehen, aber der ursprüngliche Satz muss nicht?

Comment: @Ken, doch. Der erste Satz ist auch nach diesem Muster gebaut. Da ist ein "es" ausgelassen. Der wirklich volle Satz wäre: Danach wurde **es** nicht weiter ...  
Das kommt meistens vor, wenn wir einen "impersonal sentence" haben, und ein Adverb oder Pronoun auf der ersten Stelle steht: Grundform: Es wurde gefeiert. (there was celebrating). Aber: Danach wurde gefeiert. Hier wurde gefeiert.

Comment: @Dan das ist nicht richtig. Man unterstellt zwar in gewissen Theorien ein Null-Pronomen oder unsichtbares Pronomen, aber das heißt nicht, dort müsste tatsächlich eines stehen. Die gesamte Phrase kann als das an dritter Stelle stehende Objekt betrachtet werden. // Die Behauptung zu "weiter bauen" ist mir neu, die Aussage geradezu paradox. Du denkst wohl an *erweitern*, dass ich eher als "ausbauen" kenne. Beziehst du dich auf Fachsprache?

Comment: @vectory ich finde, solche Therien bieten eine gute Erklärung. 
Allerdings wollte ich zuerst tatsächlich erst auf https://wortwuchs.net/grammatik/praepositionalgruppe/ hinweisen.

Zu erweitern: da bin ich etwas überfordert, wenn dir da eine Korrektur einfällt, kann ich sie gerne in meiner Antwort übernehmen.